# How to deliver instance of object to instance of SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tcp, socketserver

This is problem.
My primary work is : deliver "s" object to "handle" method in TestRequestHandler class. 
My first step was : deliver "s" object through "point" method to TestServer class, but here im stuck. How to deliver "s" object to TestRequestHandler? Some suggestions?

```
import threading
import SocketServer
from socket import *

class TestRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
        return

    def setup(self):
        return SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.setup(self)

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(1024)

        if (data): 
            self.request.send(data)
            print data

    def finish(self):
        return SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.finish(self)

class TestServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, handler_class=TestRequestHandler):
        print "__init__"
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler_class)
        return

    def point(self,obj):
        self.obj = obj
        print "point"

    def server_activate(self):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.server_activate(self)
        return

    def serve_forever(self):
        print "serve_forever"
        while True:
            self.handle_request()
        return

    def handle_request(self):
        return SocketServer.TCPServer.handle_request(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    address = ('localhost', 6666)
    server = TestServer(address, TestRequestHandler)
    server.point(s)
    t = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever())
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Comment: I am confused.  Your server is opening a socket on localhost:6666.  What is this other socket you're creating and trying to "point"?  Is that supposed to be a client socket for testing?

Comment: I'm also a little confused. By "deliver" are you referring to inter-thread communication? Or are you trying to make a remote procedure call, sending the object to the server over the wire? I confess I don't understand what you mean by "point".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I think you perhaps are misunderstanding how the module works.  You are already specifying an address of 'localhost:6666' for the server to bind on.

When you start the server via your call to serve_forever(), this is going to cause the server to start listening to a socket on localhost:6666.

According to the documentation, that socket is passed to your RequestHandler as the 'request' object.  When data is received on the socket, your 'handle' method should be able to recv/send from/to that object using the documented socket API.

If you want a further abstraction, it looks like your RequestHandler can extend from StreamRequestHandler and read/write to the socket using file-like objects instead.

The point is, there is no need for you to create an additional socket and then try to force your server to use the new one instead.  Part of the value of the SocketServer module is that it manages the lifecycle of the socket for you.

On the flip side, if you want to test your server from a client's perspective, then you would want to create a socket that you can read/write your client requests on.  But you would never pass this socket to your server, per se.  You would probably do this in a completely separate process and test your server via IPC over the socket.

**Edit based on new information**

To get server A to open a socket to server B when server A receives data one solution is to simply open a socket from inside your RequestHandler.  That said, there are likely some other design concerns that you will need to address based on the requirements of your service.

For example, you may want to use a simple connection pool that say opens a few sockets to server B that server A can use like a resource. There may already be some libraries in Python that help with this.

Given your current design, your RequestHandler has access to the server as a member variable so you could do something like this:

```
class TestServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
     def point (self, socketB):
         self.socketB = socketB # hold serverB socket

class TestRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(1024)

        if (data): 
            self.request.send(data)
            print data

        self.server.socketB ... # Do whatever with the socketB
```

But like I said, it may be better for you to have some sort of connection pool or other object that manages your server B socket such that your server A handler can just acquire/release the socket as incoming requests are handled.

This way you can better deal with conditions where server B breaks the socket.  Your current design wouldn't be able to handle broken sockets very easily. Just some thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

If the value of s is set once, and not reinitialized - you could make it a class variable as opposed to an instance variable of TestServer, and then have the handler retrieve it via a class method of TestServer in the handler's constructor.

eg: TestServer._mySocket = s

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my main task is this. Construction of the listening server (A-server - localhost, 6666) which during start will open "hard" connection to the different server (B-server - localhost, 7777).
When the customer send data to the A-server this (A-server) sends data (having that hard connection to the B-server) to B-server, the answer receives from the B-server to A-server  and answer sends to the customer.
Then again : the customer sends data, A-server receives them, then sends to the B-server, the answer receives data from the B-server and A-server send data to the customer.
And so round and round. The connection to the B-server is closes just when the server A will stop.
All above is the test of making this.

Comment: @Ozymet I revised my response